# The term 'System.DefaultWorkingDirectory' is not recognized in YAML pipeline

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I had a pipeline with PowerShell task that run some python script. It worked without any problems.
After I convert my pipeline into YAML format to store it as code and got something like this (a part of whole yaml pipeline):

```
    variables:
      Build.SyncSources: false
      REPO_PATH_DA: '/asdfg/qwerty'
      REPO_PATH_DS: '/zxcvbn/tyuio'
      PIP_REPO_HOST: 'bbbb.nnnn.yyyy.com'
      PIP_REPO_URL: 'https://$(PIP_REPO_HOST)/api/pypi/pypi/simple'
      PIP_VENV_NAME: 'my_test_venv'
      SelectedBranch: ''
      WorkingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
    
…………………………………………….

    - task: PowerShell@1
      displayName: 'Install package'
      inputs:
        scriptType: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
         .\$(PIP_VENV_NAME)\Scripts\activate
         python.exe -m pip install --index-url=$(PIP_REPO_URL) --trusted-host=$(PIP_REPO_HOST) mypackage
         python.exe -m pip install --index-url=$(PIP_REPO_URL) --trusted-host=$(PIP_REPO_HOST) $(WorkingDirectory)$(REPO_PATH_DA)\qwerty
```

And after I run this pipeline I get an error:

```
##[error]System.DefaultWorkingDirectory : The term 'System.DefaultWorkingDirectory' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I tried to change the name of variable in format: $(env:System_DefaultWorkingDirectory) , but no success. I suppose that predefined variables are not passed into yaml pipeline. Do you have any ideas how to resolve it?

Comment: Hi @GolovDanil. From you ticket tag,  it seems that you are using TFS, right? Or you are using azure devops service. You could refer to the answer and check if it could give you help. If it sill not work, you could share the agent type and version with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, the same script could work fine in my yaml pipeline. The `$(WorkingDirectory)` will be converted to paths xxx/xx/s.

To check if the predefined variable:  $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)  has been passed to Yaml Pipeline.

You could add a task to list all Environment variables:

```
steps:
- script: SET | more
```

In the task log, you could search the **SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY** and check if the variable exists.

For example:

[image]

If this environment variable exists, you could try to use the following format: `$env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY`

Here is the example:

```
   variables:
      Build.SyncSources: false
      .....
      WorkingDirectory: '$env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY'
```

If you couldn't find this variable, you can also check if there are equivalent variables.

For example:

```
BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY , BUILD_REPOSITORY_LOCALPATH
```

Comment: It is strange but I have not any of this variables. I made output of all environment variables: there are a lot of variables, but nothing about build directory. There is a env that points at D:\vsts\Agent001\_work
But it is not full path of working directory I think

Comment: @GolovDanil. Yes. It's strange. From the path, you are using the self-hosted agent. Could you please share the agent version ? You could try to create a new agent or update to the [latest version](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases/tag/v2.181.2).

Comment: On the other hand, what product are you using ? Azure Devops Service or Azure Devops Server or Tfs?

Comment: I use TFS. Finally I got temporary decision. I use some variable that points on agent's directory and manually  created new working directory there (instead of System.DefaultWorkingDirectory). It works fine, but it is still strange. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Is this a build or a release pipeline? If it's a release, you may need to use $(Pipeline.Workspace) instead of $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory).

Also, have you tried using $(System.WorkingDirectory) directly in your Powershell task, instead of declaring a variable that references it?